# Undo Operation fails on Repeated Use

Tags: c#, undo

I created an undo operation to set the current Value to the previous one that was within a list. It accomplishes this by removing the most recent index from the list and setting the value to the value that is behind it. Currently it works when there no value with in the list at initialization, as well as if there is more than one value within the list.

The code the way it is works when there is at least one index in the array, as previous unit tests pass this.

The problem is occurring where I try to have the InvalidOperationException to pass when the command is run twice, after the last item in the list has also been removed. so Add(5) -> Undo() -> Undo() to give an example. Also changing the if statement from valDict.Count > 0 to Value > 0, the same error occurs.

```
List<int> valDict = new List<int>();

 public void Undo()
    {
        repOp1 = "Undo";
        Console.WriteLine("1: " + valDict.Count);
        if ( valDict.Count > 0)
        {
            int temp = valDict.Count - 1;
            Console.WriteLine("2: " + temp);
            valDict.RemoveAt(temp);

            Console.WriteLine("3: " + valDict.Count);
            valDict.TrimExcess();
            //Below Line is flagged as the error
            Value = valDict[valDict.Count-1];
        }
        else
        {
           throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

    }
```

Can someone looking at this with fresh eyes, point out a possible solution, but not a fixed implementation, as I need to fix the implementation myself.

Comment: I suggest using a `Stack<T>` to store operations. You should read up on the Stack data structure.

Comment: You are trying to index an item in the list that you already removed.  Kaboom when there was 1 item in the list.  Move the RemoveAt() call to the bottom.

Comment: @Hans Ah thanks, it works now :)

Comment: @Andrew I'll read up on it as a way that it can be improved for a later version :)

Answer (score -1):

You can control that your List is not empty before getting the Value: list.Count==0, or !list.Any().